# Writing JSON representation of a graph

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to save a directed graph to a JSON file, it's giving me an error:

> TypeError: Object of type 'Graph' is not JSON serializable

The graph is represented as an object, my code looks like this:

```
g = {"a": ["d"],
     "b": ["c"],
     "c": ["b", "c", "d", "e"],
     "d": ["a", "c"],
     "e": ["c"],
     "f": []
     }

graph = Graph(g)

with open('graph.json', 'w') as output_file:
    json.dump(graph, output_file)
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `json` module only knows how to serialize [basic python types](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders). If you want to serialize your own `Graph` type - you need to write your own `JSONEncoder` for it, see "Extending JSONEncoder:" in the docs.

Also you can just serialize the `g`-like dict and list structure that is inside the Graph object.